# Constructor chaining and initialization syntax

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

Imagine that I have two classes, one of which is dependent on the other:

```
class A
{
public: 
    A(bool flag)
    {
    }
};

class B
{
public: 
    B(A a) :
        mA(a)
    {
    }
    A mA;
};
```

Now imagine that I also have two other classes: a base class that uses Foo and Bar, and a class that derives from that:

```
class Base
{
public: 
    Base(A a, B b) :
        mA(a),
        mB(b)
    {
    }

    A mA;
    B mB;
};

class Derived : Base
{
    Derived() :
        Base(A(true), B(????))
    {
    }
};
```

How can I construct bar here?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think that your class Bar is valid. Maybe you're just omitting things and assuming we know?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `new`?

Comment: Please compile before you post.  There are many little errors in this code which obfuscate your real question.

Comment: @JohnDibling probably because I'm coming to C++ from C# and have developed some habits over the years :). The 'new' doesn't really make sense here though - that helps. I'll try to restate my question.

Comment: @fatcat1111 Changing class names didn't _'restate'_ your question, rolled back. Using `new` is the point!

Comment: Yes, I removed the 'new' as well, at the same time. Also made the members public where needed.

Comment: @fatcat1111 Just use the `mA`member and pass it to `mB`s initializer. Ensure acessability from Derived ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Here we go - that is not possible - base class members are not initialized while passing arguments to the base class

Comment: @DieterLücking Ahh, I see! Yes, interesting point ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  Rolling the edit back to version 1 was a step back.  fatcat's edits fixed many of the little problems that was muddling this post.

Comment: @JohnDibling Yes, sorry for that! Was the 1st time I rolled back an edit, and just spotted the class name changes primarily.

Comment: @DieterLücking Could using references for the base class members help out?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  No.  Bases are initialized before members.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, that uninitialized base member is copied.

Comment: @JohnDibling & DieterLücking _' No. Bases are initialized before members.'_ Yes, that's reflecting the expressed semantics, that doesn't work here: `mA` and `mB` aren't related at 1st place.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.

Comment: @JohnDibling I'm saying that I think (guess) what the OP want's is to have a reference relation from `mB` to `mA`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  Maybe they do, but that wasn't made clear to me.  At least that's not the impression I got.

Comment: @JohnDibling My guts say you'll need to use references for a reasonable solution in c++ (at least in class `Base`). In c# you usually wouldn't need to care of that in the design.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  How do you come to that conclusion?  In order to have a reference, you need to *refer* to something that another object owns.  Who owns the `A` and `B` objects in this scenario?

Comment: @JohnDibling _'Who owns the A and B objects in this scenario?'_ `Base`??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  Yes, `Base` owns them.  They are members of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
class Derived
:
  public Base
{
public:
  Derived()
  :
    Base (true, Foo (false))
{
};
```

You don't use `new` here.  We're not in C# anymore, Toto.  `new` is for the dynamic instantiation of an object, and it returns a pointer.  You're not dynamically allocating anything here, and you don't store pointers.  You don't use `new`.

Comment: `new` isn't longer used in the question. And `Foo (false)` (`B(false)`) uses an implicit constructor of `A` which would instantiate an **unrelated** instance. The OP will **need** to use either pointer or reference to **relate** instances of classes `A` and `B`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  OP was explicitly instantiating instances of `A` and `B` in the question.  I don't see why you're suggesting using references here?

Comment: _'I don't see why you're suggesting using references here?'_ Because the OP was asking for **related** classes: "one of which is dependent on the other"

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  I took the "dependancy" to mean encapsulation.  That was pretty clearly expressed in the code posted in the question.  "Dependancy" is too vague a term since it doesn't really mean any one specific thing.  I was basing my answer on the precision applied by the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Imagine that I have two classes, one of which is **dependent** on the other ...
>         `Derived() :
>             Base(A(true), B(`**????**`))`

To design a dependency or relation for classes in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) you'll need to use references (as long you're not referring to simple *equivalent* copies of class `A` instances):

```
class A
{
public: 
    A(bool flag) { }
};

class B
{
public: 
    B(A& a) : mA(a) { }
    A& mA;
};
```

And let class `Base` do:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(bool flag) : mA(flag), mB(mA) { }

private:
    A mA;
    B mB;
};
```

To allow default construction and later assignment, use pointers (`Derived` can set `mB.mA`in the constructor body):

```
class B
{
public: 
    B() 
    : mA(nullptr) { }
    B(A* a) : mA(a) { }

    A* mA;
};
```

For the latter option, not to mention all of the variants of [c++11 or other smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) implementations (see `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::weak_ptr`) here!